# How to judge color space of processed image?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am studying the OpenCV. Now I am vary confusing the following problem.

Here is the code:

```
Mat img = imread("...");
Mat imgHSV;
Mat imgThresholded;

cvtColor(img, imgHSV, COLOR_BGR2HSV);
inRange(imgHSV, Scalar(150, 50, 75), Scalar(179, 255, 255), imgThresholded);
```

Now, I get a processed image imgThresholded. is this imgThresolded in RGB color space or HSV color space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is 1 a one channel image with either 0 or 255 values.
If you want to go back to your original RGB space just do the following:

```
cv::Mat FinalRGB;
cv::cvtColor(imgThresholded, imgThresholded, CV_GRAY2BGR);
cv::bitwise_and(imgThresholded, img, FinalRGB);
```

**EDIT:**
As @Micka stated:

```
cv::Mat imgMasked; 
img.copyTo(imgMasked, imgThresholded);
```

will do the same idea but faster.

Comment: Can't I convert imgThresholded from HVS to RGB again? I tried in code, but it  seems something wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much, I got a very satisfied answer!

Comment: instead you could: cv::Mat imgMasked; img.copyTo(imgMasked, imgThresholded); might be faster.

Comment: i don't understand why the answer selected true and voted -1

Comment: @sturkmen The vote down is on the unedited version of my answer which was a complete rubbish answer! Thanks for your care!

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#inrange),

> void inRange(InputArray src, InputArray lowerb, InputArray upperb,
> OutputArray dst)
>
> **dst** – output array of the same size as src and CV_8U type

This means that for 3 channel input image the output would be a single channel image, in case of thresholding, the output is a binary image which has only white(255) and black(0) pixels and the format is CV_8U only.

Answer (score 0):

inRange() will give binary image. Not HSV or RGB. But yeah, it will consider HSV image for computation as you have given imHSV as the input image.

The function inRange() works as follows:

imThresholded (I) is set to 255 (all 1 -bits) if imHSV (I) is 
within the specified 1D, 2D, 3D, ... box and 0 otherwise.

When the lower and/or upper boundary parameters are scalars, the indexes (I) at lowerb and upperb in the above formulas should be omitted.

Comment: It is just like normal binary thresholding. If the corresponding H,S,and V values of the image is in that range(in the scale you gave) then that pixel will be 255, if it dont lie in that range then that particular pixel value will be zero. Hope this helps!